# How run one Single after another using source from first

Tags: java, rx-java2

I have 2 Single. In first I receive token and in second I need use it, and then I must save some info from second single and return completable.
I thought do this with completable and andThen, like this:

```
String token;
IStoreProvider storeProvider;
IWebProvider webProvider;

public Completable getUserInfo(){
    return Completable.fromSingle(Completable
            .fromSingle(storeProvider
                    .getToken()
                    .doOnSuccess(x->token=x))
            .andThen(webProvider.getUserInfo(token)
                    .doOnSuccess(x->storeProvider.saveUserInfo(x)));

interface IStoreProvider{
    Single<String> getToken();
    Completable saveUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo);
}

interface IWebProvider{
    Single<UserInfo> getUserInfo(token);
}
```

But its dosen't work. How I can do it?

Comment: Please take a moment to read How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You will then be able to understand how a question should be asked on Stack Overflow and you will undoubtedly get responses from other volunteers. *"It doesn't work"* is not an appropriate way to show your problem.

Comment: Are you missing a closing paranthesis? Can you move your second single to the body of the `doOnSuccess` where you have access to `token`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stream is created before its executed, so during creation token=null and therefore you will get null in `getUserInfo`.
`flatMap` will help you.

```
public Completable getUserInfo() {
    return storeProvider.getToken()
            .flatMap(token -> webProvider.getUserInfo(token))
            .flatMapCompletable(userInfo -> storeProvider.saveUserInfo(userInfo));
}
```